# What is the best approach to estimate the differencing order of a FARIMA model?

Tags: time-series, arma

I am trying to fit a FARIMA model to a monthly discharge time series with long memory properties and forecast it. I have seen two type of approaches:

(1) estimate Hurst parameter to find d (d=H-0.5), fractionally difference the time series and fit an ARMA(p, q) model to the fractionally differenced time series.

(2) Choose orders for p and q and estimate both parameters of ARMA and fractionally differencing order (d) by methods like MLE. There are functions like `fracdiff` in "fracdiff" package for this.

Which one is the right approach? Should we estimate d before fitting FARIMA or it should be estimated simultaneously with ARMA parameters.

Comment: Check out Lidlholdt ["Long memory and ARFIMA modelling"](http://mit.econ.au.dk/vip_htm/plildholdt/Master%20thesis.pdf); this a a master thesis, so it should be detailed and accessible. Reisen et al. ["Estimation of Parameters in ARFIMA
Processes: A Simulation Study"](http://mat.ufrgs.br/~slopes/artigos/verfinal.pdf) have some seemingly relevant references in the abstract. Lardic & Mignon ["The exact maximum likelihood estimation of ARFIMA
processes and model selection criteria: A Monte Carlo study"](http://www.accessecon.com/pubs/EB/2004/Volume3/EB-04C20020A.pdf) could also be helpful.

Comment: Contreras-Reyas & Palma ["Statistical Analysis of Autoregressive Fractionally Integrated Moving Average Models"](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.1728.pdf) describe how ARFIMA is estimated in an R package. [Here](http://www.mat.uc.cl/~wilfredo/Papers/Contreras-Palma-2013.pdf) is another version of the same article. Baum's applied econometrics [slides](http://fmwww.bc.edu/EC-C/S2013/823/EC823.S2013.nn08.slides.pdf) also discuss ARFIMA estimation.

Comment: If you find an answer in the references, you could formulate it and post as an answer to your own question for others to see. I am looking forward to it.

Comment: As far as I know usually non-paremetric approaches (based on the Hurst exponent) provide a better estimate than the ARFIMA model (that is responsible to estimate several different parameters). If you want you can compare several different approaches using the Matlab Codes provided in this link: http://prorum.com/index.php/2173/calcular-expoente-exponent-dependencia-dependence-temporais

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my findings, it should not make a huge difference. This is quoted from Time Series Analysis Forecasting and Control FOURTH EDITION (By George E. P. Box et. al, 2008) page 433:

"Estimation of the parameters d, φ, θ in a fractionally integrated ARIMA
(p, d, q) process can be performed by maximum likelihood (ML) (e.g., Sowell
[268]). However, direct evaluation of the exact likelihood function is rather slow due partly to the complicated nature of the autocovariance function of the process.
Therefore, for numerical convenience, approximate ML estimation methods have
been considered by Beran [39, 40] and others. Another convenient approach is to obtain an estimate of the parameter d initially by certain methods (e.g., using a frequency domain nonparametric approach; see Geweke and Porter-Hudak [125]), and then estimate parameters φ, θ by relatively standard ML methods for the given estimate of d."